# How did MSX memory slot mapping differ between the Sharp Hotbit HB-8000 and the Gradiente Expert?

Tags: msx

I posted an answer to the question [MSX's primary and secondary slots](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27624/msxs-primary-and-secondary-slots) but while researching some references in the msx.org wiki to ensure my answer was accurate, I found some discrepancies between my recollection and the information I found.

There was an incompatibility between the way the Hotbit (HB-8000) and the Gradiente Expert mapped slots into each of the four 16kb memory pages. This I remember vividly because I had to patch some games to make them work on my machine.

What I recall is that the I/O Port A8h only worked on the Expert, while the HB-8000 required writing to a "magic" address somewhere in the address space. The mechanism on the HB-8000 actually resembles what's documented for secondary slot mapping in MSX2.

The msx.org wiki states

> the Hotbit followed MSX standards strictly unlike the competing
> Gradiente Expert

But my recollection is just the opposite: A8h I/O was the MSX Standard way of controlling the slot mapping, and the HB-8000 implementation was non-standard.

Where can I find documentation on the HB-8000 way of doing it? And which one was standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSX specification was originally defined by [The MSX Technical Data Book](https://archive.org/details/MSXTechnicalDataBook) (that particular copy being branded by Sony, with no consequence).

[Page 40](https://archive.org/details/MSXTechnicalDataBook/page/n41/mode/2up) provides the IO address map, including `PPI (8255)` between `A8` and `B0`. Skipping forwards to [page 43](https://archive.org/details/MSXTechnicalDataBook/page/n45/mode/2up) shows that port A of the 8255 is indeed intended to do primary slot selection. A peek at [the 8255 data sheet](http://aturing.umcs.maine.edu/%7Emeadow/courses/cos335/Intel8255A.pdf) shows that `A0 = A1 = 0` selects the value of port A for reading or writing.

So, in net, `A8` is defined to be the IO port that controls slots in the original MSX specification.

That being said, checking the openMSX XML descriptions of [the HB-8000](https://github.com/openMSX/openMSX/blob/835bed3bad1d3e7aa4715eb1d71d96556e521d21/share/machines/Sharp_HB-8000_1.2.xml) and [the Gradiente Expert Plus](https://github.com/openMSX/openMSX/blob/835bed3bad1d3e7aa4715eb1d71d96556e521d21/share/machines/Gradiente_Expert_Plus.xml) I notice that:

- the HB-8000 simply fills slot 3 with 64kb of RAM, like most machines; whereas
- the Gradiente Expert Plus adds secondary slots to slot 3; secondary slot 0 is its 64kb of RAM, secondary slots 1 and 2 are unfilled and slot 3 contains a demo ROM.

So that would appear to be the opposite to your recollection; the HB-8000 should always present RAM when primary slot 3 is active whereas the Gradiente Expert Plus would require you both to switch in primary slot 3 and then select secondary slot 0 within primary slot 3.